# Can you remove a sticker from fruit on shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, food, halacha

Is there a problem removing a sticker that was on your apple, orange, etc. on Shabbos?

Comment: You're not allowed to remove the unwanted object. Instead you must remove the fruit from the sticker.

Comment: Dear OP:  Please see:  https://askhalacha.com/video/removing-a-sticker-from-fruit-on-shabbat/

Answer (score 5):

Removing stickers from food can be done on Shabbos per Horav Yisroel Belsky Shlita, see Binyan Shabbos page 68. Refer to Shemiras Shabbos K’hilchoso 15:79

https://thehalacha.com/wp-content/uploads/Vol3Issue14.pdf#page=5

Answer (score 0):

The Chabad website AskTheRav.com offers a lengthy analysis of the matter in Hebrew.  It concludes in English:

> To avoid all *shaalos*, one should cut out the fruit around the sticker and leave some fruit with the sticker.

[(Source.)](https://asktherav.com/16240-can-one-remove-a-sticker-from-a-fruit-on-shabbos/)

Answer (score -2):

of course you can remove the sticker, it's not part of the fruit. you're not making something new, they are two whole and complete objects. the affixing of the sticker is not permanent, therefore it's not binyan or soser, much like tying and untying shoelaces.

Comment: But it could be tofer/korea, like gluing things together, or maybe even borrer, like peeling certain foods.

Comment: This answer would be much more valuable if backed up by sources.